# Serializing RPC-GWT

Tags: java, php, json, gwt, vb6

I'm wondering if there's a method to get a serialized string from a "string table".

What i need, is to POST some data in a web page form. This is what it sends when i do it manually:

> 7|0|48|https://aps2.senasa.gov.ar/embalaje-madera-web/embalajeApp/|03152A2DEBABDCE5D33BF4C88511DD1E|net.customware.gwt.dispatch.client.standard.StandardDispatchService|execute|net.customware.gwt.dispatch.shared.Action|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.rpc.actions.IngresarDeclaracionJuradaAction/2514804035|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.DeclaracionJurada/1628723960|java.util.ArrayList/4159755760|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.TipoEmbalajeCantidad/4152068152|java.lang.Integer/3438268394|Pallet|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.TipoEmbalaje/309031988|java.util.HashSet/3273092938|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.Contenedor/1178264080|nro contenedor 1|java.lang.Boolean/476441737|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.Despachante/3149599025|DESP||java.lang.Long/4227064769|Treyes 8978 - CAPITAL FEDERAL|gonzalo@rsystem.com.ar|Spina Gonzalo|45510141|direccion destino|direccion exportador|java.util.Date/3385151746|chasis/|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.ImportadorExportador/918958990|gonzalo@gmail.com|46326066|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.DatoAduana/2671264783|NRODESPACHO|IC01|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.LugarDeArribo/3008903128|NROMANIIMPO|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.PuntoIngreso/1183502123|717.3|aduana origen|Terrestre camion|merca|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.Pais/3238585366|AUSTRALIA|AFGHANISTAN|nombre exportador|gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.TransportePatente/1923027028|acoplado|chasis|1|2|3|4|1|5|6|7|0|0|8|1|9|0|10|1|10|0|11|0|12|0|0|11|10|126951|0|0|0|0|0|13|1|14|0|0|15|16|1|17|0|18|0|19|20|ZRCrAA|21|22|19|0|0|23|24|0|0|0|0|0|25|26|0|0|27|VnTkM$A|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|28|-11|29|0|0|19|-13|21|30|0|0|0|23|31|0|0|0|0|0|0|8|1|32|0|16|0|-18|0|0|-2|0|0|33|0|0|0|27|VnTkM$A|0|34|35|0|0|0|10|24754701|0|-18|36|19|37|0|38|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-20|39|40|41|0|0|0|42|0|43|10|10|42|0|44|10|1|0|-22|-5|45|0|0|0|-18|8|1|46|0|0|0|19|47|48|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|

I've already read  [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eG0YocsYYbNAtivkLtcaiEE5IOF5u4LUol8-LL0TIKU/edit) but as you see, this is a little more complex than the example in the documentation. I am not being able to build the payload. I need a method compatible with VB6 or PHP, or just a good explanation so i can make my own routine. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: I answered deserialization (which you may still need if you are going to do something with the results *from* the server), but you asked for serialization. The first part is still deserialization of a request, but below the break, I'll show how to serialize a request, again with as limited of information as we have in this question

---

### Request Deserialization

It may be bigger than the example in the document, but the same rules apply. For a *request* like this one, we break it down as follows, splitting on the `|` character.

> 7

Version 7.

> 0

No flags are set.

> 48

The next 48 tokens are the string table, build an array out of them. Those strings will represent the types of the data being passed, as well as actual Java Strings.

So we read the strings into a String[48], and then all the remaining numbers are either references or primitives. Data like `ZRCrAA` and `VnTkM$A` is probably a base64 encoded long. Treat this as also a list of strings, and we'll use this when we start requesting object from the data.

As the document says, we now read from the second list, the references (starts with `1|2|3|4|1|5|6|7|0|0|8...`). As we continue to deserialize, we need four more things: the url of the app, the strong name of the policy, the service class we are about to invoke, and the method name in that service class.

Since these are all string objects, we'll read strings. In `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader`, the actual Java class which would read this, we see that readString() looks like this:

```
@Override
public String readString() throws SerializationException {
  return getString(readInt());
}
```

So first we read an int, then use that to find a string. Here's getString:

```
@Override
protected String getString(int index) {
  if (index == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  // index is 1-based
  assert (index > 0);
  assert (index <= stringTable.length);
  return stringTable[index - 1];
}
```

Now, our first piece of data was the base url, read as a string. We see `1` as the int we read, then we get the (1 - 1)th string in the String[48] we created above:

> https://aps2.senasa.gov.ar/embalaje-madera-web/embalajeApp/

The strong policy name is next, `2`, which we read as

> 03152A2DEBABDCE5D33BF4C88511DD1E

The server will use this and find a file named 03152A2DEBABDCE5D33BF4C88511DD1E.gwt.rpc, outlining a security policy of what can be created on the server (so as to prohibit a hacker from just creating any kind of objects on your server).

Next we look for the service class, `3`:

> net.customware.gwt.dispatch.client.standard.StandardDispatchService

And finally the method to invoke, `4`:

> execute

From here, you need to know what `StandardDispatchService.execute` - we know that it takes only one argument, probably an `Action` instance, since we see `1` indicating one argument, then `5`, which if decoded as an Object means that we read the 5th string (take a look at how readObject works to see why). Without knowing what fields `Action` or the other classes have (listed below), we can't really guess as to what happens next with any certainty:

- net.customware.gwt.dispatch.shared.Action
- gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.rpc.actions.IngresarDeclaracionJuradaAction
- gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.DeclaracionJurada
- gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.TipoEmbalajeCantidad
- gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.TipoEmbalaje
- gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.Contenedor
- gov.senasa.embalajemadera.shared.domain.Despachante

(please note that I'm only guessing that these are serializable classes by their package and name - they could be just plain strings that someone decided to send over the wire as part of their request!)

---

### Request Serialization

We've already covered a lot of the basics in trying to take apart this message, so lets try to put it together. The class in the GWT client code that manages this is `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter`. The methods `prepareToWrite()` and `toString()` help set the stage a bit, showing the very first and last things we'll do around our work:

```
/**
 * Call this method before attempting to append any tokens. This method
 * implementation <b>must</b> be called by any overridden version.
 */
@Override
public void prepareToWrite() {
  super.prepareToWrite();
  encodeBuffer = new StringBuilder();

  // Write serialization policy info
  writeString(moduleBaseURL);
  writeString(serializationPolicyStrongName);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
  writeHeader(buffer);
  writeStringTable(buffer);
  writePayload(buffer);
  return buffer.toString();
}
```

The `prepareToWrite()` method starts off the stream with adding two strings - the module base url, and the policy strong name, strings you will recognize from the deserialization process. The `toString()` method shows the three stages that we will write out: The header, the string table, and the "payload", or object references and primitive values.

Why do we have Strings tracked differently from other leaf values? This way we have all the strings in one places, so that we can refer to them more than once and only send them each a single time. Contrast this with XML or JSON where every time you want to use a value, you have to write the value again, even if it is exactly the same.

The header consists of the version (latest is 7), and the flags to set (in your sample, just 0 will do).

In the superclass `AbstractSerializationStreamWriter`, there are four fields:

```
private int objectCount;
private Map<Object, Integer> objectMap = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Integer>();
private Map<String, Integer> stringMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
private List<String> stringTable = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The first is the current index of each object - we'll use that to keep track of objects we've seen before. Next `objectMap`, so that we can examine each object and check if we've seen it before, and if so, where, so that we can write a reference back to that position. The `stringMap` field does the same thing but for strings - JS treats string keys specially. Finally, the `stringTable` itself, the list of all strings we've seen, each added only once.

If you take apart a compiled application's generated Java for a service method like `List<String> filterStrings(List<String> strings, String startsWith)`, you'll see something like this:

```
ClientSerializationStreamWriter streamWriter = ...;//create with serializer
streamWriter.prepareToWrite();
streamWriter.writeString("com.acme.project.shared.MyService");//service interface
streamWriter.writeString("filterStrings");//method name
streamWriter.writeInt(2);//number of arguments to be found in the stream
streamWriter.writeObject(strings);
streamWriter.writeString(startsWith);
```

Knowing exactly what will be written for each method depends on knowing what the method signature is in Java - with just compiled GWT JS and a payload sample, it is somewhat difficult to reverse engineer. But lets carry on and see what would happen next.

The implementation of `writeObject` takes the object and first notes its type. If the object is null, then we just write a null string (a.k.a. `0`) and are done. Otherwise we check if we have already written this object before (and so write a negative number to see where to go in the payload), or we need to look up how to write the rest of that object, and serialize each field.

Each object that can be serialized must have a FieldSerializer, which describes how to encode and decode that object. There are many CustomFieldSerializers in GWT, custom implementations for a specific purpose, which tell RPC to not automatically generate a serializer. One example might be for ArrayList, if we had passed that in - `ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer` delegates to `Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase`, which does this:

```
public static void serialize(SerializationStreamWriter streamWriter,
    Collection instance) throws SerializationException {
  int size = instance.size();
  streamWriter.writeInt(size);
  for (Object obj : instance) {
    streamWriter.writeObject(obj);
  }
}
```

First we write the size of the list, so that the deserializer knows how many elements to read, and then we write each item in the list. In our case, we'll write these all as strings. Then, we'll write one *more* string, the second argument to the method.

So, we have this data in our String table:

- baseUrl
- policy string name
- "com.acme.project.shared.MyService"
- "filterStrings"
- "java.util.ArrayList"
- "java.lang.String"
- each string in the argument `strings`, and the string `startsWith`, though since we don't know if there are duplicates, we can't know if there are going to be the same number of strings.

In our payload then lets say we called `filterStrings(["a", "ab", "abc", "a"], "ab")`, we'll have references 1 (baseurl string index), 2 (policy strong name string index), 3 (service name string index), 4 (method name string index), 2 (int for number of fields to expect), 5 (class name of the `strings` list argument), 4 (number of items in the list), 6 (type of the first item in the list, string), 7 (contents of "a"), 6 (string type), 8 (contents of "ab"), 6 (string type), 9 (contents of "abc"), 6 (string type), 7 (contents of "a"), 6 (string type of second argument), and finally 8 (contents of "ab" again).

How would this look for classes like Action, DeclaracionJurada, etc? Without knowing what fields there are and what order they happen in, we can't say for sure. There is no good way just from the payload to reconstruct the contents, though if you could debug the running app just before the payload is sent, you could observe the structure of the object to be serialized, and use that to decide what you've found in the stream. I observe that there are several negative numbers in the sample stream, suggesting either that negative values are important for the use case, or there are back references and that this isn't a simple object tree, but a full graph, which will make things slightly more complicated.

---

The RPC serialization format is not complicated - I highly encourage reading the code in the various `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader` subclasses to understand what it does. From there, you should be able to parse out these two lists of values (strings and references/primitives) into actual objects, plus the structure of all of the classes that might be sent over the wire, and reimplement it in any language or framework.

Comment: First of all, thanks, but i don't need to parse data, i need to build the payload from the string table. I realized there is nothing that does what i need to do, at least, not the way i'm doing it. The explanation is really good. i'll see the way to build the payload by myself @colinalworth Thanks again

Comment: Oh sorry - I thought you were decoding payloads, not encoding them. I'll take a little time and write the opposite answer for you, but it will mostly boil down to looking at AbstractSerializationStreamWriter and reimplementing it, then emitting header, stringtable, payload in the right order. Should be done in the next day or so, will comment again to let you know.

Comment: Question updated, sorry for the delay. Let me know if you have other questions, either here or in https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt or ##gwt on freenode.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your service layer to export a more conventional REST endpoint, i probably would use a java bridge using something like [gwt-syncproxy](https://github.com/jcricket/gwt-syncproxy), and exporting a interface easyli usable in php.