Deserialize a response of GWT-RPC without source code of server
Yeah, I am attempting to read response from GWT-RPC server, without knowing server's code.
A response payload here:
//OK[0,1,-1.0,-10,0,1,31,30,0,1,8,-6,20,-109,8,0,-1.0,8,-1.0,8,-10,-2,8,-6,-2,8,-6,-10,8,-10,8,-1.0,-6,-68,-1,8,26,14,26,14,26,14,27,14,26,14,26,14,6,1,0,1,-1.0,9,0,1,3,0,8,8,"RA14SAAAA",4,1,1,25,"RA14SAAAA",4,8,0,2,-6,20,"XTaRkAAAA",4,0,1,-5,0,8,"XqF3kN7",4,0,"QplDyAAAB",4,0.0,24,1.0,24,19,"RaW36AAAB",4,23,1,1,0,1,38,54,3,-43,21,20,2020,0,0,8,0,1,"XTaRkAAAA",4,8,0,1,5,14,37,14,2,1,8,0,0,1,"SA2O0AAAA",4,8,0,-1.0,0,0,1,-5,0,1,-5,-6,-5,8,0,10,0,0,-6,-10,"XthsrAf",8,0.0,0,1,0,18,-76,8,-1,8,-6,0,0,8,0,1,-5,-6,-1.0,8,-31,-1,0,1,0,1,0,1,8,0,1,0,1,0,1,"Xt75NcA",4,0,1,8,"XDrwpIAAA",4,17,"XqBW$N3",10,-6,9,0,36,32,19,35,14,1,1,34,-6,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,33,0,1,11,0,1,0,8,0,1,0,1,-9,-1.0,0,1,8,-6,-2,8,-6,-10,8,-1.0,-9,-6,-1.0,8,8,-6,0,1,"ZKJuYEV",4,10,9,8,32,10,19,"RaW36AAAB",4,-5,0,0,1,0.0,0,0,1,2,0,1,-1.0,-10,0,1,31,30,0,1,8,-6,20,"XTaRkAAAA",4,8,0,0.0,8,0.0,8,-10,0,8,-6,-2,8,-6,-10,8,-10,8,0.0,"XpR8KuP",4,0,29,-1,8,26,14,28,14,26,14,26,14,28,14,27,14,26,14,7,1,0,1,-1.0,29,0,1,3,0,8,8,"RA14SAAAA",4,1,1,25,"RA14SAAAA",4,8,0,2,-6,20,"XTaRkAAAA",4,0,1,-5,0,8,"XqF3PXg",4,0,"WPk2qAAAB",4,0.0,24,1.0,24,5,"WgaDyAAAB",4,23,1,1,0,1,22,29,3,2,3,21,20,2020,0,0,8,0,1,"XTaRkAAAA",4,8,0,1,0,1,19,0,0,1,"SA2O0AAAA",4,8,0,-1.0,0,0,1,-5,0,1,-5,-6,-5,8,0,10,0,0,-6,-10,"Xs_z1OK",8,0.0,0,1,0,18,"WgaDyAAAB",4,8,-1,8,-6,0,0,8,0,1,-5,-6,-1.0,8,4,3,-1,0,1,0,1,0,1,8,0,1,0,1,0,1,-6,0,1,8,"XDrwpIAAA",4,17,"XqBW$N4",10,-6,9,0,16,7,5,15,14,1,1,13,-6,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,12,0,1,11,0,1,"SS0I6AAAB",4,8,0,1,0,1,-9,0.0,0,1,8,-6,-2,8,-6,-1,3,8,-1.0,1,3,-6,0.0,8,8,-6,0,1,"XqOUdJm",4,10,9,8,7,6,5,"P__________",4,0,3,0,0,1,0.0,0,0,1,2,2,1,["java.util.ArrayList/4159755760","test.CourseMember/2152131043","java.lang.Integer/3438268394","java.lang.Long/4227064769","126348","___MyClassName___","BT","","___CourseId___","___CourseName___","test.Class/2324027827","rnec7e2","___ClassSchedule___","java.lang.String/2004016611","___ClassSchedule2___","___ClassUrl___","1.4-0.6-0.4,"___SemesterInfo___","126346","20203","AB","50","test.TeacherCourse/3132936799","java.lang.Double/858496421","___TeacherName___","___ClassType___","___SemesterInfo2___","___NumberOfStudent___","java.lang.Boolean/476441737","___StudentId___","___StudentName___","LT","___ClassTeamCode___","___ClassSchedule___","___ClassSchedule2___","___ClassUrl___","126347","100"],0,7]

Node that I hide some sensitive words, ex class full name ././././././TeacherCourse to test.TeacherCourse, some real variable to its name, ex https://team.microsoft.com/class1 to ___ClassUrl___.
Only thing I know is this array of json need to be read from bottom up.
The first element from bottom is 7, that mean the version.
The second element from bottom is 0, that mean the flag.
The third element from bottom is a very complex array without order. It maybe ArrayList<CourseMember>
The fifth element from bottom is size of that ArrayList.
I do not know that order, my goal is to deserialize it to pretty object, or an object with same order, example:
Arraylist:
    CourseMember1:
        https://team.microsoft.com/class1
        teacher1
        schedule1_of_class1
        schedule2_of_class1
    CourseMember2:
        https://team.microsoft.com/class2
        teacher2
        schedule1_of_class2
        schedule2_of_class2

I can guess name of variable in list. But some confusing numbers can contains order.
I have {Hex}.nocache.js file.
This data is use to render to UI.
Please feel free to request any information if you can make this response readable, or any way to debug website UI via browser. I would appreciate any any any contributions.

I will add at least 100 bounty when it available for 2 days.

More context/discussion at https://groups.google.com/g/google-web-toolkit/c/Hc5075ClBHY. As discussed there, this is functionally the same as the "Request Serialization" process at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35047887/860630, except the the payload array is backwards in responses, but the string table is the same. That is, 7 is "version", 0 is "flags", then the string table, then 1 for "type of the first object (ArrayList)", 2 for "number of items in the list", 2 for "type of the first object in the list (CourseMember)", and so on.
